# Solution Set of Augmented Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Alright, so I'm asked to find the solution set to the following augmented matrix:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&-2&0&-6&3\\0&1&8&-1&0&5\\0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Let the $n$th column represent the variable $x_n$

I'm literally in my first week of  taking linear algebra and I seem to recall something about changing matrix dimensions as being ill-advised but looking at row three (which states $x_5=0$) I can't help but think that representing the last two rows (and consequently the penultimate column) are simply useless, hence I changed the matrix to this form:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&-2&0&3\\0&1&8&-1&5\end{matrix}\right]$$

Since the only column sharing a nonzero entry on each row is the third, which represents $x_3$, I decided to use some elementary row operations and eliminate $x_3$ using--shockingly enough--elimination.

$$4x_1-8x_3=3$$
$$x_2+8x_3-x_4=5$$

Which yields this:

$$4x_1+x_2-x_4=8$$

Considering we now have one equation with three unknowns, I'm not entirely sure how I am supposed to calculate the values of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_4$ for an assignment I have been given. If someone could help me out that'd be fantastic.

Comment: I have, but another explanation wouldn't hurt

Comment: And I understand that matrix transformation you've shown, but since $x_5$ is $0$ we don't really need the fifth column or the bottom two rows.

Comment: Okay, fantastic. The wording of the question made it sound as though $a$ and $b$ (or $x_1$ and $x_2$) had specific values, not a relation to other variables that I could input, hence my confusion

Comment: On a related note, is a variable free if there is no leading entry for its respective column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44504/discussion-between-lanier-freeman-and-moo).